# Double markup for image

Tags: html

My current base theme for website is producing some strange double markup for article image and I don't know if it could be OK, or it isn't good, when inspected with Firebug it shows:

```
<figure class=" field-item even" resource="http://localhost/adapt2/sites/default/files/styles/330/public/field/image/73d7edd1405081e5433c41d9ad2ee18c_L.jpg?itok=EITSe7SP" rel="og:image rdfs:seeAlso">
<img class="image-style-330" width="333" height="333" alt="My Image Alt" src="http://localhost/adapt2/sites/default/files/styles/330/public/field/image/73d7edd1405081e5433c41d9ad2ee18c_L.jpg?itok=EITSe7SP" typeof="foaf:Image">
```

- It seems like there is hardcoded `<figure>` tag for image, and the website itself produces the usual img src tag ;

Still - I can see only 1 image but I'm not sure if this double markup may produce also double image printing?

Or is it better to remove the hardcoded `<figure>` markup?

Comment: If you don't need <figure> why have it in your code?

Comment: I don't know why - because some more clever men - coders have put it there - that's why I ask - is this something extra clever or just to remove?

Answer (score 2):

This is not double, `<figure>` is just a [container element](http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/) in HTML5.

The markup is correct, and there appears to be Javascript running which generates the images at runtime from the `resource` attribute. The effect of this is that loading the images this way stops them from blocking initial page load, making it appear more responsive to the end user.

The only dodgy part is the `resource` attribute which [formally isn't allowed on `figure` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-figure-element) - that should be `data-resource` in proper HTML5. It'll work fine though.